# Redirect loop - Link stackexchange.com account to Careers 2.0 profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, stackexchange.com

Seems to be a redirect loop blocked by Google Chrome when attempting to add my stackexchange.com account to my Careers 2.0 profile.

Fiddler shows it bouncing between:

```
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/import/stack/[user ID]?code=[auth token?]))
```

and:

```
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/oauth/authorizestack?redirectUri=http%3A%2F%2Fcareers.stackoverflow.com%2Fimport%2Fstack%2F[user ID]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be resolved, please let me know if you experience it again.

Comment: I'm currently getting it.

Comment: I tried it 3 times in last 30 days and still always getting it when I try connecting with Stackoverflow. When I'm in Chrome Dev Console I get this: `GET http://careers.stackoverflow.com/gateway/stack?code=SOME_CODE_HERE)) net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS `

Comment: I'm seeing this again so it's impossible to modify my careers profile.

Comment: ...[and yet another one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249682/how-do-i-get-around-redirect-loop-when-trying-to-link-google-profile) :/

Comment: Still seeing this error using Google Chrome Version 41.0.2272.101 (64-bit)

Comment: Can confirm this is still happening.