# How do I get around redirect loop when trying to link Google profile?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, login, redirection

I'm hitting this URL and getting an infinite redirect loop:
https://stackexchange.com/oauth?client_id=375&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2fcareers.stackoverflow.com%2fgateway%2fstack

Comment: Try logging in on Stack Overflow first then see if it helps.

Comment: That didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you were still having an issue or not but this appears related to the move to OAuth2 for Google authentication. This resulted in a duplicate account and prevented you from logging in. I've merged the duplicate into your original account and you should be able to login now.

Let us know if not!